# VB.net 2008 Oracle update within a transaction only commiting part

Tags: vb.net, oracle, transactions, odbc

We are having a funky issue, we have vb.net app which is getting an updateable data reader via a select Query into oracle.  We use ODBC for connections.

We have two tables F4201 and the f4211 the 01 table is header and the 11 is detail.

We have an update for both tables within a transaction but we are seeing that in some, seemingly random, cases only the detail gets updated and the header does not.  See the code below for example.

```
Dim cnnE1 As OdbcConnection
        Dim txn As OdbcTransaction
        Dim E1Database As String = My.Settings.SettingValue("E1Database")

Try
    cnnE1 = DbConn.CreateConnection(My.Settings.E1Conn)
    cnnE1.Open()

Catch ex As Exception
    Return ProcessReturnType.Fail
End Try
txn = cnnE1.BeginTransaction
ssql = "SELECT * FROM " & E1Database & ".F4201 WHERE SHDOCO = " & tmpTrafficOrder
If Not DbConn.GetUpdateableDataAdapter(ssql, cnnE1, daSales_Header, txn) Then
    txn.Rollback()
    Dispose_ODBC_Connection(cnnE1)
    Return ProcessReturnType.Fail
End If

If daSales_Header.Fill(dsSales_Header) > 0 Then
    'If Sales Order Header has matching records then grab the Sales Order Detail records as well
    'ssql = "SELECT * FROM " & E1Database & ".F4211 WHERE LTRIM(SDKCOO) = '" & tmpDemandLocation & "' AND SDDOCO = " & tmpTrafficOrder
    ssql = "SELECT * FROM " & E1Database & ".F4211 WHERE SDDOCO = " & tmpTrafficOrder
    If Not DbConn.GetUpdateableDataAdapter(ssql, cnnE1, daSales_Detail, txn) Then
    txn.Rollback()
    Dispose_ODBC_DataAdapter(daSales_Header)
    Dispose_ODBC_Connection(cnnE1)
    Return ProcessReturnType.Fail
    End If
end if

'This function uses sql to map XML elements from the file we receive to the Oracle Field and updated the DR with the information.
'Testing shows the DR is updated with the new values after this runs
If Not oMapping.MapObjectToDataRow(fileId, ApptNotification, drSales_Header, "ApptNotif.SalesHeader", mapSubSet, My.Settings.InterfaceType) Then
    txn.Rollback()
    Dispose_ODBC_DataAdapter(daSales_Header)
    Dispose_ODBC_Connection(cnnE1)
    Return ProcessReturnType.Fail
End If
 daSales_Header.Update(dsSales_Header)
 dsSales_Header.AcceptChanges()

'Now time for details.

If daSales_Detail.Fill(dsSales_Detail) > 0 Then
    For Each drSales_Detail As DataRow In dsSales_Detail.Tables(0).Rows
        If Not oMapping.MapObjectToDataRow(fileId, ApptNotification, drSales_Detail, "ApptNotif.SalesDetail", mapSubSet, My.Settings.InterfaceType) Then
            txn.Rollback()
            Dispose_ODBC_DataAdapter(daSales_Header)
            Dispose_ODBC_DataAdapter(daSales_Detail)
            Dispose_ODBC_Connection(cnnE1)
            Return ProcessReturnType.Fail
        End If
    daSales_Detail.Update(dsSales_Detail)
    dsSales_Detail.AcceptChanges()
    next
Else
    txn.Rollback()
    Dispose_ODBC_Connection(cnnE1)
    Return ProcessReturnType.Skip
End If

 txn.Commit()
 txn.Dispose()
cnnE1.Close()
cnnE1.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation we found that it was not the transaction that was at fault, it was updating the table correctly, there was a separate process running was changing the values back.